# App crashes when I try to switch from fragment to activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments in Main Activity and one of them has a button which I want to start Activity 2. I created interface in the third fragment and extended the Main Activity with it, but I cannot figure out why my app still crashes. I lost 2 days on that issue and its driving me nuts. My Activity 2 is declared in the Manifest file. Please help!!!

Profile.Fragment:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView tv_name,tv_email,tv_message;
    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private AppCompatButton btn_change_password,btn_logout, btn_ok;
    private EditText et_old_password,et_new_password;
    private AlertDialog dialog;
    private ProgressBar progress;

    public interface OnProfileListener{
        void onProfileButtonOkClicked();
    }

    private OnProfileListener mCallBack;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile,container,false);
        initViews(view);
        return view;

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
        tv_name.setText("Здравей, "+pref.getString(Constants.NAME,"")+"!");
        tv_email.setText(pref.getString(Constants.EMAIL,""));
        btn_ok=(AppCompatButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
        btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCallBack.onProfileButtonOkClicked();
            }
        });


    }

//I have API16 and I cannot run my app with 
//onAttach(Context context) because it is supported by API>=23, 
//but Android deprecated  API16, so that is why I  use both Activity and Context

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override 
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
            if (activity instanceof OnProfileListener){
             mCallBack = (OnProfileListener) activity;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnProfileListener");
        }
    }}
    @TargetApi(23)
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnProfileListener) {
            mCallBack = (OnProfileListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnProfileListener");
        }
    }

...
    private void initViews(View view){

        tv_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_email = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        btn_change_password = (AppCompatButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_chg_password);
        btn_logout = (AppCompatButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
        btn_ok=(AppCompatButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
        btn_change_password.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_logout.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

   //Here I go to other fragment in Main Activity flawlessly, wish I could manage to go Activity2 with the same ease

    private void goToLogin(){

        Fragment login = new LoginFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,login);
        ft.commit();
    }         
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ProfileFragment.OnProfileListener{

    private SharedPreferences pref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pref = getPreferences(0);
        initFragment();
        onProfileButtonOkClicked();
    }
    @Override
    public void onProfileButtonOkClicked() {

        Intent intent=new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void initFragment(){
        Fragment fragment;
        if(pref.getBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,false)){
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();

        }else {
            fragment = new LoginFragment();
        }
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame,fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Will you post the crash log please.

Comment: My app starts on the mobile and then crashes, I do not see an error in the Event Log, it writes  BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Comment: So your app crashes on launch?

Comment: Yes, and if I put this line from MainActivity in comment:
       // onProfileButtonOkClicked();
it starts and works until I click on that button.

Comment: If there is no log there is not much I can help you with. Ensure the device is selected with filters (including the text field) If it crashes there is a log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make intent from fragment to activity add this,,

```
     public void functionname(View v)
     {
        Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(in);
     }
```

here, add this line in .xml file of that activity where the button is located

android:OnClick="functionname"

and "MainActivity2.class" is next activity to move.

"aim is to click on button to go to mainactivity2.class via that intent...

hope it will help..thanks,,

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't start another activity when the first activity is still in the state of being created.  I have no idea why you are starting activity2 before the button is tapped.
If you need to, you can put the onProfileButonOKClicked() in onCreated() handler of activity.

Comment: My aim is to start Activity2 when the button is tapped and this is the reason I added  onProfileButtonOkClicked(); because I think its something as  OnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

You should try this with **getActivityContext**

```
public void functionname(View v)
     {
        Intent in = new Intent(getActivityContext(), MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(in);
     }
```

When you call this method ..make sure you are inside **onCreate**

```
  mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                functionname(v);

            }
        });
```